# suggestions required for leaf blower?

Tags: tree

There are 5 huge trees are in my house. So we face sanitation issues all the time. I am thinking to buy a good leaf blower to keep my home clean. what leaf blower you will suggest for home users?

Comment: Leaf blowers blow fines from the topsoil into the air. The mobilized dust is an inhalation hazard. You might try running a mulching lawnmower over the leaves. If you feel you must *remove* the leaves, would you consider raking and either bagging (paper bags) for municipal pickup or composting on site?  When you say "sanitation" what specifically are you referring to? Leaves by themselves are messy, but not unsanitary.

Comment: What is the matter with rakes nowadays?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I like electric one. Snagged the cheapest one from Home Depot and on full power it blows pretty well.

If your sanitation issue is on grass, a leaf blower may not solve your issue. A metal rake will work better in some cases.

Comment: One of my friend recommending gas leaf blower.these are high prices but reliable and long life. I am thinking to buy Makita BHX2500CA because many reviewrs recommended it. like this one https://leaf-blower.net/best-gas/